# VBA IE Automation WebSite Login Button not working

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, browser-automation

The username is being populated, but the button will only work after I have physically clicked into the username field with my mouse....

```
HTMLDoc.getElementById("loginForm-email").Focus
HTMLDoc.getElementById("loginForm-email").Click
HTMLDoc.getElementById("loginForm-email").Value = "A Username"
HTMLDoc.getElementById("loginForm-next").Focus    
HTMLDoc.getElementById("loginForm-next").Click
```

website login page  https://www.britishgas.co.uk/identity/

HTML as follows

```
<!---->  
<div>
<div class="container login index mt6">
<!---->
<!---->
<h1 class="h2 text-center">Access account
</h1>
<div id="ember427" class="ember-view">
<form id="ember444" class="form-behaviour-default text-center no-success form-behaviour-default text-center unsubmitted ember-view">
<div id="ember471" class="scroll-anchor scroll-anchorerror ember-view">
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-12">
<div id="ember474" class="has-feedback form-group has-error pristine untouched ember-view">        
<label for="loginForm-email">Email address</label>
<input name="username" autocapitalize="none" id="loginForm-email" class="form-control text-center ember-text-field ember-view" type="text">
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback">
</span> 
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback">
</span>
<p id="loginForm-email-error" class="form-control-error">
<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> We need an email address from you    
</p>
</div>    
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group text-center">
<button style="touch-action: manipulation; -ms-touch-action: manipulation; cursor: pointer;" type="submit" id="loginForm-next" class="bg-button btn btn-primary ember-view">      
<span aria-hidden="true" class="bg-button-icon fa fa-angle-right">
</span>        Next
</button>  
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="text-center mb4">
<a style="touch-action: manipulation; -ms-touch-action: manipulation; cursor: pointer;" href="#/forgotten-details/forgotten-email" id="ember488" class="btn btn-tertiary ember-view">        
<span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-angle-right">
</span>I've forgotten my email
</a>    
</div>
</div>
```

end of HTML

Comment: Could you add the HTML code of the form?

Comment: Can you share the URL? And are you allowed to download software to use for automating browsers? When adding HTML please ensure you use the snippet tool in the edit options; it is an icon that looks like a document with <> on it. Ensure you include enough HTML that we can see if any javascript events are associated with the element or its immediate ancestors in particular.

Comment: The website is https://www.britishgas.co.uk/identity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me, though as using fictional info it then prompts for more info:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.britishgas.co.uk/identity/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        With .document.getElementById("loginForm-email")
            .Focus
            .Value = "joe.bloggs@internet.com"
        End With
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        With .document.getElementById("loginForm-next")
            .Focus
            .Click
        End With

        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I copy and paste your code but It does not work for me ? on clicking the button it should go to the next page prompting for a password.  I am using Excel / VBA on Windows 10 IE 11.  Maybe it is to do with some setting in IE ?

Comment: I have updated. The above seems to work for me with/without the additional wait time. You can try comenting out wait line first, then increasing wait time if non-responsive.

Comment: I put Msgbox("OK to continue..."), still does not work for me .

Comment: OK it is working :-), it seems the wait is necessary between populating the element "loginForm-email" and pressing the button...  GREAT !! Thank you very much.

Comment: Guys, a problem, it works on my computer but not on another , I'm don't know what the problem could be? same ver windows and IE.

Comment: And what is the error message? You shouldn’t really de-select this answer but rather ask a new question and ask why the code isn’t working. You can always link back to this.

Comment: Its the same as before putting the wait instruction. After putting the wait instruction the button could then be pressed on yours and mine, but on this third computer I don't know why it still is not doing anything when pressing the button on this third computer it is the same code being used ??  Another difference everytime IE loads the login page it prompts to accept cookies.